# ROS and binaries deployment

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I often have the need to arrange demos involving robots.
What I would like to do is to somehow freeze the whole ROS environment, by exporting all the dependent ROS packages associated to my demo, in order to get a standalone self-contained demo version that I can run at every moment, without dealing with ROS updates, my own package updates, and so on.

In a nutshell, I'm looking for any ROS approach to move from development to production without wasting too much time.

Any idea about this?

Thanks
Gabriele

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46574/ros-and-binaries-deployment/) by [Gabriele](https://answers.ros.org/users/3445/gabriele/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-10-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gabriele](https://answers.ros.org/users/3445/gabriele/) on 2012-10-23**:
Demos are run on a single robot, but many different users might run the same demo over time. One problem is that our own packages are very often changed. On the other hand, even upgrading ROS might introduce inconsistencies in the code. That's why I'm looking for freezing the whole environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It might be useful if you described in more detail what your demos do. Like do they always run on the very same robot, or should they run on many robots, do you want other people to install your code to run demos, and such.

If you work from source, then you can create a demo.rosinstall file which specifies all ROS packages required for your demo in the specific version they are required in.
With that, at any time you can create a folder, rosinstall all from that file, and you will get all the ROS packages in that version, which you can then compile and run.
Depending on the other factors this might be a good solution for you or not work out at all, so consider this as just one idea.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-10-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know this is a bit of an old question, but since it was asked [snaps](https://snapcraft.io) have been developed. Check them out, they support Catkin and all dependencies are bundled. There's a [ROS tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/Packaging%20your%20ROS%20project%20as%20a%20snap) introducing them. One a snap is created, that snap is immutable and should always run, which sounds exactly like what you're looking for.

---

Originally posted by [kyrofa](https://answers.ros.org/users/20478/kyrofa/) with karma: 347 on 2017-07-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1